# Determine if producer is outpacing consumer in pipeline

Tags: pipe, stdout, stdin, stdio

If I have:

```
node foo.js | node bar.js
```

is there a way to determine if there is a queue in between them that's building up?
in other words if the producer is outpacing the consumer w.r.t. stdio?

Comment: If it were Linux, one way I can think of is to run `strace` on the two processes and see if either were blocking on `read`/`write` calls.

Comment: Similar (duplicate?): [Print current number of bytes in a pipe](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/330374)

Comment: You could also have the producer use `poll()`/`select()` to check if the pipe is full. Or do non-blocking I/O and take action upon EAGAIN (meaning the pipe is full)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Print current number of bytes in a pipe](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330374/print-current-number-of-bytes-in-a-pipe)

Comment: Your usage of the term _stdio_ indicates a possible confusion. `stdio` is the C API than deals with `FILE` objects which implement their own buffering on top of file descriptors. For instance if your producer uses that API and does a `puts("foo")`, with default buffering settings, that `foo` will *not* be written to the pipe, the data is only written upon `fflush()` or when the stdio buffer is full.

Comment: Can't happen. The kernel manages buffer space for the pipe; the reader is started when there is something to read, the writer stopped when it is full.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ioctl(,FIONREAD,)` on pipes in Linux to get the current number of bytes available to read. This might be found in `man 7 pipe` (`FIONREAD` is also in `man tty_ioctl`). You can either integrate this into your application or run something like this bit of perl in parallel with it, using the pipe as stdin:

```perl
#!/usr/bin/perl
# https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/440361/119298
use strict;
require 'sys/ioctl.ph';
my $v = pack("l",0);
$| = 1;
# while(1)
{
  die "ioctl: $!" if ioctl(STDIN, &FIONREAD, $v)!=0;
  my @r = unpack("l",$v);
  printf "%d ",$r[0];
#  sleep 1;
}
```

So the usage would be

```
node foo.js | (myperl & node bar.js)
```

Try it out with something like

```sh
while sleep 1;do date;done |
while sleep 1.1;do myperl 2>/dev/null; dd status=none count=1 bs=20;done
```

I get warnings from `perl` about `_FORTIFY_SOURCE`, hence the stderr redirection. The `dd` reads less than the length of `date` so you can see the result gradually increasing.

For completeness, you can get the capacity of a pipe with `fcntl(,F_GETPIPE_SZ)` and set it with `fcntl(,F_SETPIPE_SZ,newvalue)` up to `/proc/sys/fs/pipe-max-size` (unless root or have `CAP_SYS_RESOURCE`). See `man fcntl`.